# Unit of Work Exception Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.4

That is very weird, when I try my code in developer and works fine, but, in production give me a 500 error while I try get the results.

**var/logs/prod.log**:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: "Call to a member function setValue() on null" at /my_route/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 2745 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function setValue() on null at /my_route/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:2745)"} []
```

Entities implicated:
**Contract**

```
class Contract
{
/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Id()
 */
private $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $duration;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $nifHolder;

/**
 * @var Hotel
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Hotel", inversedBy="contractHotel")
 */
private $hotel;
```

And **Hotel**

```
class Hotel
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Id()
     */
    private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      max = 100,
 *      maxMessage = "El nombre no puede tener más de 100 caracteres"
 * )
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="El nombre es obligatorio")
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      max = 200,
 *      maxMessage = "La dirección no puede tener más de 200 caracteres"
 * )
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="La dirección es obligatoria")
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200, nullable=false)
 */
private $address;
  /**
   * @var Contract
   * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Contract", mappedBy="hotel")
  */
private $contractHotel;
```

The route which I have 500 error code:

```
/**
     * @Route("/contract_list/{hotel}", name="view_contract")
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
     */
    public function listContractAction(Request $request, Hotel $hotel )
    {
        /** @var EntityManager $em */
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $contract = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('c')
            ->from('AppBundle:Contract', 'c')
            ->where('c.hotel =:hotel')
            ->setParameter('hotel', $hotel->getId())
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

        if($contract == []) {
            $contract = new Contract();

            $em->persist($contract);
            $contract->setDuration(0);
            $contract->setHaveOpticalFiber(false);
            $contract->setHaveRadioFibraPTP(false);
            $contract->setOpticalFiberOperator('Not defined');
            $contract->setHotel($hotel);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->render('contract/viewContract.html.twig', [
            'contract' => array_key_exists(0, $contract) ? $contract[0] : $contract,
            'hotel' => $hotel

        ]);
```

In database all are fine, mapped is validate, even when I do $em->flush(); row are insert

EDIT: Is posible that my error is caused because I use "composer install --optimize-autoload" before add the entities?

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

```
        $em->persist($contract);
        $contract->setDuration(0);
        $contract->setHaveOpticalFiber(false);
        $contract->setHaveRadioFibraPTP(false);
        $contract->setOpticalFiberOperator('Not defined');
        $contract->setHotel($hotel);
        $em->flush();
```

to this:

```
        $hotelEntity = $em->getRepository(AppBundle\Entity\Hotel::class)->find($hotel);

        $contract->setDuration(0);
        $contract->setHaveOpticalFiber(false);
        $contract->setHaveRadioFibraPTP(false);
        $contract->setOpticalFiberOperator('Not defined');
        $contract->setHotel($hotelEntity);
        $em->persist($contract);
        $em->flush();
```

When you make `setHotel` you need to pass an entity not an id

Comment: Yes, the contract is created, but when I query it, I have the same error :(

Comment: I have added a line before @JoseAntonioMoral

Comment: Its works, Now I can insert data, but when I do " ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();" give me an error

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm dummy, the solution is simple: restar apache and... it's works!